# Can't enter date into postgres field with datatype reltime

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I'm trying to make an insert into postgres 8.4.13

```
insert into my_table (id, hour_memo) values (1,'17:30:00.000000 +01:00:00');
```

hour_memo is 'reltime datatype'

During the execution of the insert task i have this trouble:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type reltime: "17:30:00.000000 +01:00:00"
```

I have absolutely no idea on how to do this?

Comment: Why did you choose to use "reltime" datatype? Documentation says explicitly: `The types abstime and reltime are lower precision types which are used internally. You are discouraged from using these types in applications; these internal types might disappear in a future release.`

Comment: While @depesz comment is correct, that is not a reason to downvote the question (whoever did it) as it is useful exactly to highlight that that type should not be used.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that reltime doesn't support time zones, so the "+01..." thing is breaking it. Still - using reltime type is bad idea, and should be replaced by some normal type.